# iOS UICollectionView lags with scrolling at start

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview, smoothing

I use a simple UICollectionView in ma iOS in my project.

The view loads about 100 Cells. The Problem appears even if a let the Cells empty.

After ViewDidLoad the Collection view Appears. When i start Scolling about the first three screen Pages down it lags - even with empty cells!

after that i becomes smooth. I also can get top of the page and try again. Scrolling kepps smooth.

Comment: Xcode [Instruments tools](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) are your fiends.

Comment: How can they help to see why the Collection View lags at start?

Comment: You'll see what's keeping the main thread busy and causing UI lags for UI updates.

Comment: you have an idea how to go with it? i am very new to ios and never used instruments before.

Comment: Thank you very much! Instruments showed lag in NSSQL... which was because of high usage of google analytics.

Comment: Long press Run button at the top-left corner, select `Profile` there. When the `Instruments` app is launched, select one of the presets (e.g. Time Profiler might be helpful for you in this case). You can find guidelines and presets description at the link above, the tools are quite intuitive though. I'd recommend you to pause profiler as soon as you have recorded this laggy behavior, then look for the issues at the Call Tree.

Comment: No problem, you might want either to edit the question with the new details or provide the details as an answer for this particular problem (which is to find the source of a problem :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 2 reasons that you might also encounter

### 1. Google analytics

If you set up to count every cell view. It starts fast but then slows down and lags because google analytics writes i/o (maybe some caching) as you scroll too fast.

### 2. DateTime Parsing

DateFormatter is hard if you setup for every cell. Make sure you have a singleton if possible.